# Add and remove table row using DOM Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have problems making the delete button. Although I somehow managed to make it, after I click (use the delete button) that removes the table row that I click on this button (`save_button.addEventListener("click", hahah);`) stops working. That is the button that adds a new row in the table. I click it and nothing happens. Should I make the delete button some other way or is it something else? I am new in javascript so I would really appreciate your support.

```
var lastindex = 1;

var save_button = document.getElementById("contacts-op-save");

save_button.addEventListener("click", hahah); 

function hahah(event)
{
    var x1 = document.getElementById("first_n").value;
    var x2 = document.getElementById("last_n").value;
    var x3 = document.getElementById("e_mail").value;


    event.preventDefault();

    var table = document.getElementById("contacts-table");

    var row = table.insertRow(lastindex);

    lastindex++;

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);


    cell1.innerHTML = lastindex-1;
    cell2.innerHTML = x1;
    cell3.innerHTML = x2;
    cell4.innerHTML = x3;
    cell5.innerHTML =  
    "<input id='edit-"+ (lastindex-1)  +"' value='Edit' type='button'/>" +
    "<input id='delete-"+ (lastindex-1) +"' value='Delete' onclick = 
    'deleteRow(this)' type='button'/>" +
    "<input id='save-"+ (lastindex-1) +"' value='Save' type='button'/>";        

    var saveBtn = document.getElementById("save-"+ (lastindex-1));
    saveBtn.style.display = "none";

    var editBtn = document.getElementById("edit-"+ (lastindex-1));

    var deleteBtn = document.getElementById("delete-"+ (lastindex-1));



    editBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
        saveBtn.style.display = "inline";
        editBtn.style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("delete-" + (lastindex-1)).style.display = 
    "none";
        var inputFirstName = document.createElement("input");
        inputFirstName.type = "text";
        inputFirstName.id   = "first_name-" + (lastindex-1);
        inputFirstName.value = x1;
        cell2.innerText = "";
        cell2.appendChild(inputFirstName);

        var inputLastName = document.createElement("input");
        inputLastName.type  = "text";
        inputLastName.id    = "last_name-" + (lastindex-1);
        inputLastName.value = x2;
        cell3.innerText = "";
        cell3.appendChild(inputLastName);

        var inputEmail = document.createElement("input");
        inputEmail.type = "text";
        inputEmail.id = "email-" + (lastindex-1);
        inputEmail.value = x3;
        cell4.innerText = "";
        cell4.appendChild(inputEmail);



});
saveBtn.addEventListener("click", function()
{
    saveBtn.style.display = "none";
    deleteBtn.style.display = "inline";
    editBtn.style.display = "inline";
    var first_name = document.getElementById("first_name-" + (lastindex-
    1)).value;
    var last_name = document.getElementById("last_name-" + (lastindex-
    1)).value;
    var edited_email = document.getElementById("email-" + (lastindex-
    1)).value;

    cell1.innerHTML = lastindex-1;
    cell2.innerHTML = first_name;
    cell3.innerHTML = last_name;
    cell4.innerHTML = edited_email;

    })

}

   function deleteRow(row)
   {
     var d = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
     document.getElementById('contacts-table').deleteRow(d); 
   }
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser's dev console? Please create a working snippet using `<>` demonstrating your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the issue is with this line

```
var row = table.insertRow(lastindex);
```

Since you are also removing a row, your lastindex value may not be reflecting the correct value since as per [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow#Syntax)

> row is assigned a reference to the new row. A reference to
>   HTMLTableRowElement. If index is -1 or equal to the number of rows,
>   the row is appended as the last row. If index is greater than the
>   number of rows, an **IndexSizeError** exception will result. If index is
>   omitted it defaults to -1.

Just make it

```
var row = table.insertRow( -1 );
```

to make sure that **row is inserted at the end only**.

Comment: It works. I never would have thought that that line might be a problem. You saved me a lot. All the time i thought it had something with the delete button. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Glad it worked for you :) , please accept and upvote the answer that has helped you.